# Android: is it possible/advised to interact with a Bound Service from Adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-service-binding

I have some complex data modeled by a data class, with both immutable and mutable fields:

```
data class book (
    val ISBN: String,
    val Author: String,
    ...
    var borrowed: Boolean
)
```

And I'm trying to find a way to display a number of instances of it in a RecyclerView.
I reckon the Adapter's only concern is to *display* data, however, passing a whole bunch of objects doesn't seem really sensible to me, expecially since not all the fields of all the instances would need to be displayed.

So I decided to use a list of ISBN as the Adapter's **DataSet** and, when needed, fetch the corresponding object from a Bound Service.

However, I'm not sure this is the right way, as the Adapter doesn't have a clear Lifecycle, and I can't figure where to bind/unbind to the service.

The question then becomes:
In an Android Adapter, where should I bind to a Bound Service, in order to fetch the data to display? Is doing so some sort of design heresy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing it the wrong way. The way you wanna do it is really bad in term of performance.
Passing a whole bunch of objects doesn't seem really sensible to you, but it is right way to use a recyclerview for best performance and avoid weird behavior.

If you want to retrieve data from a service :
- initialize you recyclerview with an empty dataset (loading ... )
- run your service to retrieve your dataset
- notify your activity and pass your dataset
- your activty change your recyclerview adapter with a new dataset
- your recyclerview "notifyDataSetChanged()" to display new dataset

Comment: all above steps are done by google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library